# Android AlertDialog.Builder - good OnClickListener item id practice?

Tags: android, menu, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

Suppose I want to create a simple dialog using AlertDialog.Builder. Is there any nice way to get rid of written "by hand" comparison to integers in it's OnClickListener?

I can make some constants, but it still is something that has to be changed in 2 places, if somebody adds another item to menu.

```
final CharSequence[] menuOptions = new CharSequence[]{"one","two","three"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapBrowsingActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Choose action").
        setItems(menuOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    //do sth;
                }
                if (which == 1) {
                    //do sth;
                }
                if (which == 2) {
                    //do sth;
                }
            }
        });
builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use next approach which is based on usage of `enum`. It requires additional stuff with converting `enum` to `CharSequence`, but guarantees that when you or another developer will add/remove/insert new menu app would work ok.

```
private void showMenu() {
    final Menu[] values = Menu.values();
    CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        items[i] = values[i].toString();
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose action").
            setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Menu value = values[which];
                    switch (value) {
                        case Menu1:
                            break;
                        case Menu2:
                            break;
                        case Menu3:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

private enum Menu {
    Menu1,
    Menu2,
    Menu3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do anything about it. If somebody changes the menu items, also the handling should be changed. You could use a `switch` to make it a little clearer though:

```
switch(what) {
    case 0:
        //do sth;
        break;

    case 1:
        //do sth;
        break;

    case 2:
        //do sth;
        break;

    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("item unknown");
}
```